# Viewing the resultant source code of a file in rails when it has lot of mixins included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

I have rails application which uses loads of engines. The controller logic is composed of a mixture of included mixins. I have to go to each mixin individually before I can trace what the code is doing. is there any tool which can show me the resultant source code file with all the resultant methods so I can easily find out what is happening

Comment: Easily, eh? You could find yourself reading 10MB ruby file. And no, I don't know such tool.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that I know of that does exactly what you want.

However, you can see exactly what's being run simply by raising an exception in your controller action or even your view and looking at the stack trace. Things like [better_errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors) make the process of digging through stack traces much more pleasant than it sounds.

You can also do things like `ApplicationController.included_modules` and `ApplicationController.new.methods` but I'd think the stack trace method would be much less frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

[Pry](http://pryrepl.org/) is a good tool for exploring what's available on a complicated object. Just add this to your `Gemfile`...

```
group :development do
  gem 'pry-rails'
end
```

...`bundle install`, and `rails console` will launch a pry console instead of an irb one. Pry lets you look up a method's source with the `$` command, including telling you where it's defined:

```
[11] pry(main)> module SomeModule
[11] pry(main)*   def hidden_method
[11] pry(main)*     puts "hello!"
[11] pry(main)*   end
[11] pry(main)* end
=> :hidden_method
[12] pry(main)> class AClass
[12] pry(main)*   include SomeModule
[12] pry(main)* end
=> AClass
[13] pry(main)> a = AClass.new
=> #<AClass:0x007f23b431d588>
[14] pry(main)> $ a.hidden_method

From: (pry) @ line 9:
Owner: SomeModule
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 3

def hidden_method
  puts "hello!"
end
```

Comment: I was going to say RubyMine is free-as-in-beer, and has integrated code browsing and debugging, to do more than that automatically & graphically, but I suppose the more vim-like the interface, the more programmerly we feel about it. C-;